# libgdx - Image artifacts when downscaling image

Tags: textures, libgdx, sprites, scale

Why does this border appear around the edges when I downscale a bitmap and how do I avoid it? I tried every filter I know, the results go from bad to worse.

[image: Border problem]

Here's the original bitmap:

[image: original bitmap]

Comment: I do not think changing your sampling filter is going to fix this... is this a pre-multiplied alpha image? I suspect you are not properly dealing with that.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know libgdx, but **the problem is with your image**. There are low opacity, white-ish pixels all around the edges of the Moon (ARGB is around `(1, 255, 255, 255)`)

It's important to be aware of the fact that all pixels in an image have R, G and B values, even the ones where alpha is zero, and they might cause artifacts during sampling. There is a detailed article on this here: [article](http://www.adriancourreges.com/blog/2017/05/09/beware-of-transparent-pixels/).